# How to install npm packages correctly in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

I have a default CI image, assume its name is `ci:default`, and it can be, and must be run by `-d` arguments. I want to install some `npm` packages in it and then use the new image as my customized CI image. Here is how I try to do:

1. `docker pull ci:default`
2. use `docker run -it ci:default /bin/bash` to run and enter the container.
3. In that container, use `npm i -g XXX` to install npm packages I need, and it works.
4. use `apt-get update` to save the changes I did to the container.
5. exit the container, and then use `docker commit` command to create my customized image, let's name it by `ci:customized`.

So far so good, as I thought. But when I try to run the new image by using `docker run -d ci:customized`, it cannot be run successfully, and I don't know when I did wrong since I'm new to docker.

Can somebody please tell me how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your exact issue is because you didn't post an error message but there is a much better way to create an image with the packages you want by using dockerfiles

create a file called `Dockerfile`

in it you can do something like

```
FROM ci:default
RUN npm install
```

You can then use docker build to build that in to an image. Check [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for docker build but you should just need something like `docker build --tag ci:customized`

The benefit of doing it this way is you now have a text file documenting how to set up your image so when you need to modify it later you don't forget what steps were performed before.

Comment: The reason I did't post any error message is that there is none. Everything works fine, but the result comes out wrong.

Comment: I got it figured out. It turns out that the entry point is different from the original image